# Hudson: How to trigger cleanup shell after a build is failed?

Tags: build, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I am using Hudson framework, and I want to have a feature that, when the build process (the step of `execute shell`) failed, another cleanup shell script will be executed no matter what.

The current behavior is once the executed shell exit because of failure, all the following up actions will be neglected and email will be triggered for failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Parameterized Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) will allow you to set up your cleanup script as a separate Hudson job and then trigger it from your first build, regardless of whether the first build passes or fails.